# msbuild: command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument /Werror

Tags: github, installation, msbuild, repository, gnu-make

I am a student of TU Wien and quite new in programming. I would like to install a GitHub repository (https://github.com/SICKAG/sick_safetyscanners_base) which is basically for Linux, but I asked one the of the contributors and he said it should work on windows too.

According to the README the following steps have to be done to install this the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/SICKAG/sick_safetyscanners_base.git
cd sick_safetyscanners_base
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<path to install folder> ..
make -j8
make install
```

Here is a list of the softwares and tools I have already installed:

1. Visual Studio 2022 Community (because of MSVC)
2. Visual Studio Code
3. Scoop (to install cmake and make)
4. Boost 1.80.0
5. Git

And here are all the commands which are just working fine:

```
git clone https://github.com/SICKAG/sick_safetyscanners_base.git
cd sick_safetyscanners_base
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON .. (-DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON, otherwise cmake does not find boost)
```

The problem is in the command line "make -j8". After this command, I recieve the following message: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop. I have done some research and I found out that make will not work on windows (I use windows 10).

```
PS C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base> mkdir build


    Directory: C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        09/11/2022     13:04                build


PS C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base> cd build
PS C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\build> cmake -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.33.31630.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Found Boost: C:/boost/boost_1_80_0 (found version "1.80.0") found components: system thread chrono atomic
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/ader/sick_safetyscanners_base/build
PS C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\build> make -j
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Since Make will not work, I tried the command "msbuild" in the Developer PowerShell for VS 2022, but the repository will still not be installed, because I have the following error message: command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument /Werror.

```
PS C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\build> msbuild sick_safetyscanners_base.vcxproj
MSBuild version 17.3.1+2badb37d1 for .NET Framework
Build started 09/11/2022 13:07:41.
Project "C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\build\sick_safetyscanners_base.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
Project "C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\build\sick_safetyscanners_base.vcxproj" (1) is building "C:\Users\ader\
sick_safetyscanners_base\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "x64\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\".
  Creating directory "x64\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "x64\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
CustomBuild:
  Checking Build System
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "x64\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "x64\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\ZERO_CHECK.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "sick_safetyscanners_base.dir\Debug\".
  Creating directory "C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\build\Debug\".
  Creating directory "sick_safetyscanners_base.dir\Debug\sick_saf.78B012DA.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "sick_safetyscanners_base.dir\Debug\sick_saf.78B012DA.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was spe
  cified.
CustomBuild:
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/ader/sick_safetyscanners_base/CMakeLists.txt
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /IC:\User
  s\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\include /IC:\boost\boost_1_80_0 /Zi /nologo /Wall /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /
  D _WINDLL /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D sick_safetyscanners_base_EXPORTS /Gm- /EHsc /R
  TC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"sick_safetyscanners_base.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"sick_s
  afetyscanners_base.dir\Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W4 /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue  -std=c++11 -Werror C:\Users\ader\sic
  k_safetyscanners_base\src\SickSafetyscanners.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\ApplicationNameVari
  ableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\ChangeCommSettingsCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_saf
  etyscanners_base\src\cola2\CloseSession.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\Cola2Session.cpp C:\User
  s\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\Command.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\ConfigMetadata
  VariableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\CreateSession.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscann
  ers_base\src\cola2\DeviceNameVariableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\DeviceStatusVariabl
  eCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\FieldGeometryVariableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_saf
  etyscanners_base\src\cola2\FieldHeaderVariableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\FieldSetsV
  ariableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\FindMeCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanne
  rs_base\src\cola2\FirmwareVersionVariableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\LatestTelegramV
  ariableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\MeasurementCurrentConfigVariableCommand.cpp C:\Us
  ers\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\MeasurementPersistentConfigVariableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetys
  canners_base\src\cola2\MethodCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\MonitoringCaseTableHeaderVa
  riableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\MonitoringCaseVariableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\si
  ck_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\OrderNumberVariableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\Proj
  ectNameVariableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\RequiredUserActionVariableCommand.cpp C:\
  Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\SerialNumberVariableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\
  src\cola2\StatusOverviewVariableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\TypeCodeVariableCommand.
  cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\cola2\UserNameVariableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_ba
  se\src\cola2\VariableCommand.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\communication\TCPClient.cpp C:\Users\ader
  \sick_safetyscanners_base\src\communication\UDPClient.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\
  ParseApplicationData.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseApplicationNameData.cpp C:\U
  sers\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseConfigMetadata.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base
  \src\data_processing\ParseData.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseDataHeader.cpp C:\
  Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseDatagramHeader.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_bas
  e\src\data_processing\ParseDerivedValues.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseDeviceNa
  me.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseDeviceStatus.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscan
  ners_base\src\data_processing\ParseFieldGeometryData.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\P
  arseFieldHeaderData.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseFieldSetsData.cpp C:\Users\ad
  er\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseFirmwareVersion.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\d
  ata_processing\ParseGeneralSystemState.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseIntrusionD
  ata.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseMeasurementCurrentConfigData.cpp C:\Users\ade
  r\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseMeasurementData.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\da
  ta_processing\ParseMeasurementPersistentConfigData.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\Par
  seMonitoringCaseData.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseOrderNumber.cpp C:\Users\ade
  r\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseProjectName.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_p
  rocessing\ParseRequiredUserAction.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseSerialNumber.cp
  p C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseStatusOverview.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanner
  s_base\src\data_processing\ParseTCPPacket.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseTypeCod
  eData.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\ParseUserNameData.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetys
  canners_base\src\data_processing\TCPPacketMerger.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\data_processing\UDPPa
  cketMerger.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\ApplicationData.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safety
  scanners_base\src\datastructure\ApplicationInputs.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\Applic
  ationName.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\ApplicationOutputs.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safe
  tyscanners_base\src\datastructure\CommSettings.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\ConfigDat
  a.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\ConfigMetadata.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_b
  ase\src\datastructure\Data.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\DatagramHeader.cpp C:\Users\a
  der\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\DataHeader.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructur
  e\DerivedValues.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\DeviceName.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safety
  scanners_base\src\datastructure\DeviceStatus.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\FieldData.c
  pp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\FieldSets.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\
  datastructure\FirmwareVersion.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\GeneralSystemState.cpp C:\
  Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\IntrusionData.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\da
  tastructure\IntrusionDatum.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\LatestTelegram.cpp C:\Users\a
  der\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\MeasurementData.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastr
  ucture\MonitoringCaseData.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\OrderNumber.cpp C:\Users\ader\
  sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\PacketBuffer.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\
  ParsedPacketBuffer.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\ProjectName.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_sa
  fetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\RequiredUserAction.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\S
  canPoint.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\SerialNumber.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscann
  ers_base\src\datastructure\StatusOverview.cpp C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\TypeCode.cpp C
  :\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\src\datastructure\UserName.cpp
cl : befehlszeile  error D8021: Ungültiges numerisches Argument /Werror. [C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\build\
sick_safetyscanners_base.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\build\sick_safetyscanners_base.vcxproj" (default targets)
 -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\build\sick_safetyscanners_base.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  cl : befehlszeile  error D8021: Ungültiges numerisches Argument /Werror. [C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\buil
d\sick_safetyscanners_base.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.43
```

At this stage, I do not really know, what else should I try to get this lilbrary finally installed. My goal is to call it with #include in my C++ program.

Do you have a solution here on how to get rid of the error message and how to install this library? I think the only thing missing is this step. I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Thank you in advance!

== UPDATE after the answer of MadScientist ==

Brief history: After installing boost, I got the following message...

```
The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

        The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

                C:\boost\boost_1_80_0

        The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

                C:\boost\boost_1_80_0\stage\lib
```

... but I don't know exactly where to put these paths. I'm assuming that's exactly why Cmake doesn't find Boost. This problem was solved with `-DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON`.

Now, if I use the command line `cmake -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON -G "Unix Makefiles" ..`, CMake fails to find Boost again.

Here is what I can see on the terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\build> cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/mingw64/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE
CMake Error at C:/Users/ader/scoop/apps/cmake/3.24.3/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: system thread chrono) (found version
  "1.80.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/ader/scoop/apps/cmake/3.24.3/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Users/ader/scoop/apps/cmake/3.24.3/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2376 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/ader/sick_safetyscanners_base/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
PS C:\Users\ader\sick_safetyscanners_base\build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make absolutely does work on Windows (if you install it).  In fact, you can tell it works since you ran it and it worked!!

The problem is that `cmake` can create project files for lots of different build systems, and the default on Windows is Visual Studio, not make.  So when you ran `cmake` you got a bunch of files that tell Visual Studio how to build your code, but no files that tell `make` how to build your code.

Delete the directory and unpack it again, then run `cmake` again and add the `-G "Unix Makefiles"` option to the command.

However, the option `-Werror` is an option to the GCC compiler.  It won't work if you're trying to run the Visual Studio compiler (even if you use a makefile to build the code, it will still use the Visual Studio compiler to compile it).

My suspicion is that whomever told you that "it should work" to build this code on Windows, was overly optimistic and in fact it will require some porting effort to make this work.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your prompt answer! I tried the option -G "Unix Makefiles". If I use -G "Unix Makefiles" and -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON at the same time, CMake does not find Boost.

Comment: I am updating my question in a minute to adequately explain the current problem.